# What is better to use (CqlConnection and CqlCommand) or (Cluster and Session)

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is there an advantage to using one or the classes to execute statement in a .Net application.  As a .Net developer using CqlConnection and CqlCommand is very similar what is done for other dbs (like SqlServer).  I read on some web sites that Cluster and Session is a better way to go.

The documentation in DataStax does not describe the differences or any suggestions of which to use under what circumstances.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the cluster and session objects in the DataStax driver

DataStax drivers provide critical functionality for enterprise cassandra apps, including configurable load balancing policies, automatic failover, retry policy, and tunability. These features are exposed via the cluster and session objects.

Notice that CqlConnection and CqlCommand are not even mentioned in the [**DataStax documentation**](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/csharp-driver/1.0/csharp-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html). This is because they are used under the hood by the driver.

You can certainly use these to connect and read/write to cassandra but you will be missing out on the features I mentioned.

**Pro Tip**: Check the code comments **[here](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/8b88562a7239d3591a4a4f3416f3eafba78a49ec/src/Cassandra/Cluster.cs)** to see the functionality of the Cluster object. DataStax drivers are Open Source so feel free to go code diving!